# How to enable App Group in Xamarin IOs

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin, mobile

I am trying to enable app group in my ios application(Entitlements.plist), but for some reason Xamarin gives me an error that I don't have any Apple developer Accounts. When I am trying to add one, xamarin suggests to Authenticate with Fastlane and nothing is happening.

[image]

I have no idea why Xamarin can't see my apple IDs account.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have Fastlane installed and configuered? When you click ok in the popup it shows your image what happens?

Comment: Yes, I have installed Fastlane. When I click ok in the popup, terminal is opened. In the terminal I am putting username and password of my Apple IDs, but unfortunately Xamarin doesn't receive my ctedentials. It looks like the xamarin can't syncronize with my apple account.

Comment: Do you have enabled 2-factors authentication with Apple?

Comment: Yes. Is this the reason?

Comment: I had your problem last week and disabling the 2-factors fixed the problem. It seems it's on Apple, although I read some where that using VS for Mac it worked even with the 2-factor